# Eclipse INDIGO freeze everytime when I run python program

Tags: python, freeze, eclipse

My Eclipse is downloaded some days ago from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ and the type is Eclipse Classic 3.7.1.

I installed pydev in Eclipse and configuration python in **Windows** -> **Performance** -> **Pydev** -> **Interpreter - Python**.

After everything finished, I write a hello world program, but when I try to run (**Run** -> **Run as** -> **Python Run**) it, the Eclipse would freeze in everytime!! Yes, Everytime!!

Has anyone met this strange questions?

my configurations:

**Eclipse**: 3.7.1; **Pydev**: 2.3.0; **Python**: 2.6.2; **Java**: 1.7.0

The Pydev installed method is: go to **Help** -> **Install New Software**, and added the pydev updated address: **http://pydev.org/updates**, and installed

Comment: You mean freeze that it does not recover? Can you run Python programs normally without freezes from command-line?

Comment: Python program can be ran successful by IDLE, VIM, SciTE, pythonwin... it just cannot ran by Eclipse, I using Eclipse to debug and analysis steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got the answer, that's all because ANSICON, I was install the ANSICON http://adoxa.110mb.com/ansicon/ for BDD. The purpose of ANSICON is to make command line colorful(that's really beautiful!), but, it seem change something and make Eclipse freeze. Well, if wants Eclipse works, just uninstall the ANSICON.